# Multiple borrow of disjoint fields of structure under mutex lock

Tags: rust

I have a structure that is mutex protected and I want to mutate different fields of the structure:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Test {
    foo: usize,
    goo: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Mutex::new(Test { foo: 0, goo: 0 });
    let mut y = x.lock().unwrap();
    let a = &mut y.foo;
    let b = &mut y.goo;
    *a += 1;
    *b += 1;
}
```

This is not allowed:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `y` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
11 |     let a = &mut y.foo;
   |                  - first mutable borrow occurs here
12 |     let b = &mut y.goo;
   |                  ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
13 |     *a += 1;
   |     ------- first borrow later used here
```

This code works if the struct is used without the `Mutex`. I am assuming this is because even though it looks like I am using the structure directly here, its all working via `DerefMut` and that won't allow mutating disjoint fields? This is a common usage pattern where we lock a structure and change multiple fields, so how do I work around this?

Comment: The duplicate [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96e219bb049d74c6df88a635884455ee).

Comment: Thanks for the response, the borrow_mut() indeed fixed my problem!